# The equation $x^3 + y^3 = z^3$ has no integer solutions - A short proof

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, alternative-proof

Can someone provide the proof of the special case of [Fermat's Last Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) for $n=3$, i.e., that 
$$
x^3 + y^3 = z^3,
$$ 
has no positive integer solutions, as briefly as possible?

I have seen some good proofs, but they are quite long (longer than a page) or use many variables. However, I would rather have an elementary long proof with many variables than a complex short proof.

**Edit.** Even if the bounty expires I will award one to someone if they have a satisfying answer.

Comment: “I have seen some good proofs, but they are quite long (more than a page) or use many variables.” Welcome to mathematics!

Comment: When the exponent is a prime, use & abuse Newton's binomial theorem. All the terms of any row of Pascal's triangle whose index is a prime number divide through it. This is what ultimately makes the Diophantine equations $a^p+b^p=c^p$ impossible, starting with $p=3$. It's a fairly simple (but very laborious) question of exploiting divisibility. With all primes $>2$ out of the way, their multiples soon follow, so all that's left is $n=4$. You inevitably arrive at a point where the product of two terms equals a product of *n* terms. For $n=2$ this works, but not for $n=p>2$, due to co-primality.

Comment: @Lucian Well, *that* even seems to fit a book's margin.

Comment: @Lucian Can you add a bit more detail and post that as an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, as I've already said, my proof for $n=3$ is also quite long (though by no means complex), and it does use quite a few extra variables, so...

Comment: Most proofs use factorization in $\Bbb Z[\zeta_3]$, as far as I know. Oh, oh, you want rational-points-on-elliptic-curves? Sure, it would reduced a variable in the calculation!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem_for_specific_exponents#n.C2.A0.3D.C2.A03

Comment: @Lucian if it's not complex, I would like to see it

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Main idea.** The proof that follows is based on the [infinite descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent), i.e., we shall show that if $(x,y,z)$ is a solution, then there exists another triplet $(k,l,m)$ of smaller integers, which is also a solution, and this leads apparently to a contradiction.

Assume instead that $x, y, z\in\mathbb Z\smallsetminus\{0\}$ satisfy the equation (replacing $z$ by $-z$)
$$x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 0,$$ 
with $x, y$ and $z$ pairwise coprime. (Clearly at least one is negative.) One of them should be even, whereas the other two are odd. Assume $z$ to be even.

Then $x$ and $y$ are odd. If $x = y$, then $2x^3 = −z^3$, and thus $x$ is also even, a contradiction. Hence $x\ne y$.

As $x$ and $y$ are odd, then $x+y$, $x-y$ are both even numbers. Let
$$
2u = x + y, \quad 2v = x − y,
$$
where the non-zero integers $u$ and $v$ are also coprime and of different parity (one is even, the other odd), and 
$$
x = u + v\quad \text{and}\quad y = u − v.
$$
It follows that
$$
−z^3 = (u + v)^3 + (u − v)^3 = 2u(u^2 + 3v^2). \tag{1}
$$
Since $u$ and $v$ have different parity, $u^2 + 3v^2$ is an odd number. And since $z$ is even, then $u$ is even and $v$ is odd. Since $u$ and $v$ are coprime, then
$$
 {\mathrm{gcd}}\,(2u,u^2 + 3v^2)={\mathrm{gcd}}\,(2u,3v^2)\in\{1,3\}.
$$

Case I. $\,{\mathrm{gcd}}\,(2u,u^2 + 3v^2)=1$.

In this case, the two factors of $−z^3$ in $(1)$ are coprime. This implies that $3\not\mid u$ and that both the two factors are perfect cubes of two smaller numbers, $r$ and $s$.
$$
2u = r^3\quad\text{and}\quad u^2 + 3v^2 = s^3.
$$
As $u^2 + 3v^2$ is odd, so is $s$. We now need the following result:

**Lemma.** *If $\mathrm{gcd}\,(a,b)=1$, then every odd factor of $a^2 + 3b^2$ has this same form.*

*Proof.* See [here.](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2005/05/fermats-last-theorem-n-3-a2-3b2.html)

Thus, if $s$ is odd and if it satisfies an equation $s^3 = u^2 + 3v^2$, then it can be written in terms of two coprime integers $e$ and $f$ as
$$
s = e^2 + 3f^2,
$$
so that
$$
u = e ( e^2 − 9f^2) \quad\text{and}\quad
v = 3f ( e^2 − f^2).
$$
Since $u$ is even and $v$ odd, then $e$ is even and $f$ is odd. Since
$$
r^3 = 2u = 2e (e − 3f)(e + 3f),
$$
the factors $2e$, $(e–3f )$, and $(e+3f )$ are coprime since $3$ cannot divide $e$. 
If $3\mid e$, then $3\mid u$, violating the fact that $u$ and $v$ are coprime. Since the three factors on the right-hand side are coprime, they must individually equal cubes of smaller integers
$$
−2e = k^3,\,\,\,
e − 3f = l^3,\,\,\,
e + 3f = m^3,
$$
which yields a smaller solution $k^3 + l^3 + m^3= 0$. Therefore, by the argument of infinite descent, the original solution $(x, y, z)$ was impossible.

Case II. $\,{\mathrm{gcd}}\,(2u,u^2 + 3v^2)=3$.

In this case, the greatest common divisor of $2u$ and $u^2 + 3v^2$ is $3$. 
That implies that $3\mid u$, and one may express $u = 3w$ in terms of a smaller integer, $w$. Since $4\mid u$, so is $w$; hence, $w$ is also even. Since $u$ and $v$ are coprime, 
so are $v$ and $w$. Therefore, neither $3$ nor $4$ divide $v$.

Substituting $u$ by $w$ in $(1)$ we obtain
$$
−z^3 = 6w(9w^2 + 3v^2) = 18w(3w^2 + v^2)
$$
Because $v$ and $w$ are coprime, and because $3\not\mid v$, then $18w$ and $3w^2 + v^2$ 
are also coprime. Therefore, since their product is a cube, they are each the cube of 
smaller integers, $r$ and $s$:
$$
18w = r^3 \quad\text{and}\quad
3w^2 + v^2 = s^3.
$$
By the same lemma, as $s$ is odd and equal to a number of the form $3w^2 + v^2$, 
it too can be expressed in terms of smaller coprime numbers, $e$ and $f$:
$$
s = e^2 + 3f^2.
$$
A straight-forward calculation shows that
$$
v = e (e^2 − 9f^2) \quad\text{and}\quad w = 3f (e^2 − f^2).
$$
Thus, $e$ is odd and $f$ is even, because $v$ is odd. The expression for $18w$ then becomes
$$
r^3 = 18w = 54f (e^2 − f^2) = 54f (e + f) (e − f) = 3^3 \times 2f (e + f) (e − f).
$$
Since $3^3$ divides $r^3$ we have that $3$ divides $r$, so $(r /3)^3$ is an integer 
that equals $2f (e + f) (e − f)$. Since $e$ and $f$ are coprime, so are the three factors $2e$, $e+f$, and $e−f$; therefore, they are each the cube of smaller integers, $k$, $l$, and $m$.
$$
−2e = k^3,\,\,\,
e + f = l^3,\,\,\,
e − f = m^3,
$$
which yields a smaller solution $k^3 + l^3 + m^3= 0$. Therefore, by the argument of infinite descent, the original solution $(x, y, z)$ was impossible.

**Note.** See also [here.](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2005/05/fermats-last-theorem-n-3-a2-3b2.html)

Comment: Can you present the proof all together?

Comment: I incorporated a proof, using a simple lemma: http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2005/05/fermats-last-theorem-n-3-a2-3b2.html

Comment: But the infinite descent only works for positive integers.. You should show that there is a positive solution which gets progressively smaller..so at least one of the positive solution of $(x,y,z)$ gets smaller.. It is not immediately clear to me why is it so

Answer (score 2):

There’s a wonderful elementary (and fairly short) proof in [this paper by S.Dolan](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23249523).

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1017/S0025557200004034

Answer (score 1):

Eight years and one elementary number theory course later, I can give a brief but not as elementary sketch of an answer based on the ring of [Eisenstein integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer). They have a strong connection to cubes, considering the cubic root of unity $\omega$. Assume it is already established the Eisenstein integers $\mathbb Q(\omega)$ are a Euclidean domain, so UFD. This answer follows that in Dörrie's *100 great problems of elementary mathematics*, but he spends some pages reproving results about Euclidean domains.

First off we can assume in $\alpha^3 + \beta^3 = \gamma^3$ that $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are coprime in the Eisenstein integers due to unique factorization. By trivially replacing $\gamma$ with $-\gamma$ the equation is $\alpha^3 + \beta^3 + \gamma^3 = 0$.

Now $i\sqrt 3 = \omega - \omega^2 = 2 \omega + 1$ is an Eisenstein prime by properties of norm. (Dörrie calls this $J-O$, where he defines $J = - \omega^2 = (1 + i \sqrt 3)/2, O = - \omega = (1-i \sqrt 3)/2$. He uses $\{J, O\}$ as a basis instead of $\{1,\omega\}$ or $\{\omega, \omega^2\}$ for some reason?)

By some basic computations and casework of $a,b$ mod 3 I'm too lazy to write up, if 3 divides $a + b$ then $i \sqrt 3$ divides $a + b \omega$, and more calculations show Lemma: if $i \sqrt 3$ doesn't divide $a + b\omega$, then $(a + b\omega)^3 \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 9$.

Now Lemma: $\alpha^3 + \beta^3 + \gamma^3 = 0$ implies $i \sqrt 3$ divides exactly one of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$. This holds because suppose $i \sqrt 3$ didn't divide any of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$. Then $\alpha^3 \equiv e, \beta^3 \equiv f, \gamma^3 \equiv g \pmod 9$ where $e^2 = f^2 = g^2 = 1$. But by casework mod 9, this is impossible. And we know $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are coprime so can't share a factor of $i \sqrt 3$.

Finally, $\alpha \beta \gamma \ne 0$ is impossible by some arguments of common divisor and infinite descent on the norm given in [R. Andrew Ohana's more algebraic proof](https://wstein.org/edu/2010/414/projects/ohana.pdf). Actually I should've just linked his proof instead of writing all the above, since the algebraic structure is more enlightening. But I'll leave the answer as a source of references and getting down ideas.

Answer (score -1):

Assume $x^3+y^3=z^3$, $x$, $y$, $z$ c0-prime, $x$ even, $y$ odd, $z$ odd.

Let $x+y=z+d$. Cubing the latter, subtracting the hypothesis: $$3x^2y+3y^2x=3z^2d+3d^2z+d^3.$$ Transposing and
substituting:
$$3(z+d)(xy-zd)=d^3.$$
$3\mid d$, so let $d=3e$. The equation becomes:
$$3(z+3e)(xy-3ze)=27e^3.$$ Dividing by $3$,
$$(z+3e)(xy-3ze)=9e^3.$$
The left side is divisible by $e^3$.
However, each factor cannot be divisible by $e$, or else $e\mid(z+3e)$, or $e\mid z$, and $e\mid (xy 3ze)$, or $e \mid xy$. Hence $e\mid(z\text{ and }x)$ or $e \mid (z\text{ and }y)$, which is impossible because co-prime.

$e\ne1$ because we would have $(z+3)(xy-3z)=9$.

$9$ divides the left side, but both factors cannot be divisible by $3$,or $3 \mid z$ and $3 \mid xy$, impossible.

Returning to
$$(z+3e)(xy-3ze)=9e^3,$$
we repeat the argument just completed to get the result:
the 2 factors on the left can only be divisible be $e^3$, $9e^3$, $1$, and $9$,so we have the $4$ possibilities:
(a) $z+3e=9e^3$, $(xy-3ez)=1$;
(b) $z+3=e^3$, $(xy-3ez)=9$
(c) $(z+3e)=9$, $(xy-3ez)=e^3$,
(d) $(z+3e)=1$, $(xy-3ez)=9e^3$.
Now (d) and (c) are clearly impossible. In (a) and (b), the expression $xy-3ez=xy -dz$ is the difference of 2 even numbers; their difference could not be $1$ or $9$. Q.E.D.   Ed Gray

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. You claim that $(z+3)(xy-3z) = 9e^3$ is impossible if $x,y,z$ are coprime with $x$ even and $y,z$ odd. But your 'argument' is totally invalid. (It is already invalid for $e = 1$, but by luck you made a true claim.) You have **many more than** 4 possibilities. A counter-example is not needed to invalidate your argument, but in this case there is one: $(x,y,z,e) = (2,1461,95,10)$.

Comment: The comment by user    21820 used the erroneous equation (z + 3)(xy - 3z).

Comment: user21820 made a typo in the equation, but also gave an explicit counter example which checks out in the actual equation: namely subbing $(x,y,z,e) = (2,1461,95,10)$ into your equation $(z+3e)(xy-3ze) - 9e^3$ gives $0$.