# Without solving it, is there an elementary way to show that $X^3+Y^3=Z^3$ has a finite number of primitive [and non-trivial] integer solutions?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, cubics

Considering the cubic case of Fermat’s Last Theorem, I make the following claim:

**Proposition:** The Diophantine equation
$$
  X^3 + Y^3 = Z^3  \tag{$\star$}
$$
has a finite number of primitive [and non-trivial] integer solutions $(x,y,z)$.

Is there a *simple and elementary* way to prove this statement?

**Note:** I am aware of Wiles’s proof of FLT in the general case, and the infinite descent proof of the cubic case by Euler *et al.*, and the Mordell–Weil theorem, *etc.* I’m just curious, independent of those things, whether this weaker proposition has a simple and elementary proof.

Comment: So you mean really different, since if $x,y,z$ is a solution so is $(ax,ay,az)$.

Comment: You never know. You should be aware of Selmer's example, $3x^3 + 4 y^3 + 5 z^3.$ There are no local obstructions to this being zero, however it cannot be zero with integers $x,y,z$ unless all three are zero. http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/selmerexample.pdf

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662313 ?

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thanks — I edited the question and Proposition accordingly. Hope it more clearly and accurately represents what I'm asking.

Comment: @WillJagy: Nice! I look forward to absorbing that.

Comment: @Watson: Yes, that question includes the infinite descent proof (originally by Euler, with corrections/completions by a few subsequent mathematicians), as mentioned in the body of my question. I'm asking a slightly different question than the full cubic case of FLT.

Comment: We can assume $X$ and $Y$ are relatively prime WLOG. Let them have a common factor $p$. $$X^3 + Y^3 =Z^3 \Longleftrightarrow (px)^3 + (py)^3 = (pz)^3 \Longleftrightarrow x^3 + y^3 = z^3$$

Comment: @Dhruv: Okay… and then?

Comment: Kieren MacMillan, $x^3+y^3=z^3$

Suppose  $z=x+d_1$ and $y=x+d_2$ also $y>x$  ⇒ $d_2<d_1$. Substituting in equation we get:

$x^3 +3x^2(d_2-d_1) +3x(d_2^2 -d_1^2)-d_1^3=0$

Now If you claim equation $x^3+y^3=z^3$ have a solution then you have to prove the equation $x^3 +3x^2(d_2-d_1) +3x(d_2^2 -d_1^2)-d_1^3=0$ has a solution. You can either use standard algorithm for cubic equations or reasoning to show this. I think this could be a simple elementary method.

Comment: @sirous: I think you mean $x^3+3x^2(d_2−d_1)+3x(d_2^2−d_1^2)+d_2^3-d_1^3=0$, right?

Comment: Kieren MacMilan, you are right, sorry about the mistake. Meanwhile I used this algorithm to find a general formula for finding Pythagorean triples.

Comment: Kieren MacMilan, We can write: $z^3-y^3=x^3$ or $(z-y)(z^2 + zy + y^2)= x . x^2$  suppose $x=z-y$, it  contradicts $x^2=z^2+zy+y^2$. we may assume $z-y=1$. among $z, y$ couples only $z=8$, $y=7$ give  one term, i.e. $8^3-7^3=13^2$. For others usually the terms are more than one. One way is to search whether there exist more such triples and if so $x$ is a cube?.

Comment: @sirous: What justification do we have for assuming $z-y=1$?

Comment: We have to assume $x^3=z^3-y^3$ or $x^2=z^3-y^3$ and $x =1$. This is another possibility when assuming $z-y=x$ contradicts other factor.

Comment: @sirous: Why can’t $z-y=x_1^3$ and $z^2+yz+y^2=x_2^3$, where $x=x_1x_2$?

Comment: The equation is supposed to have only one solution for each parameter.

Comment: @sirous: Sounds like you’re mixing up "solution" with "integer". In my __one solution__, I simply factor $x=x_1x_2$ where $x_1, x_2 > 1$.